# Ruby Method Calling

Tags: ruby, function, methods

I plan on working with Ruby for a school project and just delved into it for the first time this week. While playing around with the "case" functionality, I found something interesting. I tried writing a method that takes a string, checks what string it is with the "case" and prints another string according to the case:

```
def identify_class(str)
print "Enter a value: "
str = gets.chomp
case obj
  when "Hacker" 
  puts 'Its a Hacker!'
  when "Submission" 
  puts 'Its a Submission!'
  when "TestCase" 
  puts 'Its a TestCase!'
  when "Contest" 
  puts 'Its a Contest!'
  else
  puts 'Its an unkown model'
end
```

I then tried calling it with the following:

```
identify_class "Hacker"
end
```

However, the result on the console is only ":identify_class". Other methods I wrote work just fine; for example, the following takes an integer and returns the square.

```
def sqr(x)
    return x*x
end
```

If I call it with

```
sqr(5)
```

I get 25 from the console. I've also tried writing the case outside of a function and it prints the prompt, takes the input and returns the proper phrase like so:

```
print "Enter a value: "
obj = gets.chomp
case str
when "Hacker" 
puts 'Its a Hacker!'
when "Submission" 
puts 'Its a Submission!'
when "TestCase" 
puts 'Its a TestCase!'
when "Contest" 
puts 'Its a Contest!'
else
puts 'Its an unkown model'
end
```

The console returns:

```
Enter a value:  Hacker
Its a Hacker!
=> nil
```

It seems like there is something about method calling in Ruby that I can't quite put my finger on. I've tried going through some documentation and haven't found a problem similar to mine. Could someone illuminate me on why the method call isn't working as expected?

EDIT:

This is all of my relevant code.

```
def identify_class(str)
  print "Enter a value: "
  str = gets.chomp
  case str
    when "Hacker" 
      puts 'Its a Hacker!'
    when "Submission" 
      puts 'Its a Submission!'
    when "TestCase" 
      puts 'Its a TestCase!'
    when "Contest" 
      puts 'Its a Contest!'
    else
      puts 'Its an unkown model'
end

identify_class "Hacker"
end
```

If I don't have "end" after identify_class "Hacker", I get an unexpected end-of-input error.

Comment: In your code as presented, you record the result of `gets` in a variable named `str`, but then you test a different variable in your `case` statement.

Comment: This is confusing: `identify_class "Hacker"⏎end`. What does that `end` belong to? Can you post your whole code? (The short answer to your question is that method definitions (`def ... end`) evaluate to the name of the method as a Symbol, e.g. `puts def foo; end` would print `foo`. It's not clear, however, where you're defining the method and getting the result, so it's hard to answer your question.)

Comment: Changed "obj" to "str" in the identify_class method...sorry about that. Also, all of my code is there. I have the method declaration for identify_class in one code block and I am calling the method in the other block "identify_class "Hacker"⏎end". If I don't have the end there, I get a syntax error asking for "end"

Comment: I'm guessing that you got your `end`s mixed up (or maybe got an "expecting keyword_end" error and just started putting `end`s in there until the error went away) and you have a method definition inside another method definition. This could have been avoided by properly indenting your code. Again, however, we can't tell you exactly where the problem is without seeing the whole code.

Comment: Although a `case` statement works here what you really need is a simple hash look-up table like `PHRASE = { "Hacker" = "It's a hacker!", ... }` or, given how these are all identical but for the special case, then `ROLES = %w[ Hacker Submission ... ]` could define valid roles, so you could just say `"It's a #{str}"` if `ROLES.include?(str)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing an end after the case statements. Thus the console gives just the result of defining a function that is never called.

Comment: Yup, just found that as well. Thanks! This was the result of a student spoiled by curly braces and Python indentations.

Comment: @Kemilio I am not sure that I would call `python`s requirement for white space dependence "spoiled". Indenting you code properly makes it easier to read and understand but if I choose to use 3 spaces instead of 2 I would feel more disheartened than spoiled by a broken compile.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to add another "end" after using "case". The following worked for me:

```
def identify_class(str)
  print "Enter a value: "
  str = gets.chomp
  case str
    when "Hacker" 
      puts 'Its a Hacker!'
    when "Submission" 
      puts 'Its a Submission!'
    when "TestCase" 
      puts 'Its a TestCase!'
    when "Contest" 
      puts 'Its a Contest!'
    else
      puts 'Its an unkown model'
    end
end

identify_class "Hacker"
```